# Error on importing go-sql-driver/sql from github repository

Tags: mysql, go

As the title says, I have an error when importing go-mysql-driver package. I have installed the go-my-sql driver in my machine but the error still persists. I use XAMPP for local hosting and here’s the block of program.

```
package model

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

type Table interface {
    Name() string
    Field() ([]string, []interface{})
}

func Connect(username string, password string, host string, database string) (*sql.DB, error) {
    conn := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:3306)/%s", username, password, host, database)
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", conn)
    return db, err
}

func CreateDB(db *sql.DB, name string) error {
    query := fmt.Sprintf("CREATE DATABASE %v", name)
    _, err := db.Exec(query)
    return err
}

func CreateTable(db *sql.DB, query string) error {
    _, err := db.Exec(query)
    return err
}

func DropDB(db *sql.DB, name string) error {
    query := fmt.Sprintf("DROP DATABASE  %v", name)
    _, err := db.Exec(query)
    return err
}
```

```
could not import github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql (no required modules provides package "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql")
```

[screenshot of what's happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9Y70.png)

Comment: I believe the error means that your `go.mod` file is missing the `require` directive for that package.

Comment: You should also try building the program outside the IDE, i.e. directly using the `go build` tool. It's possible that your IDE is just misconfigured.

Comment: You don't "install" a non-main package, so saying you have installed it doesn't mean anything. If you ran `go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql`, it would add it to your `go.mod`. Is it listed in there properly?

Comment: I'm sorry to make everyone feel confused with what I asked. Here I am just a student taking a course where I just install vscode and go. I got the github file from the course, but I'm still confused why I got an error when I wanted to run the go coding. I'm also not good at typing English too so maybe that's what makes you all feel confused. I'm very sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

Your IDE is not showing you the whole picture. By running `go run main.go` (or whatever main file you have) on the command line, you can see the same error as you're seeing on your IDE with some extra:

```
$ go run main.go
main.go:7:5: no required module provides package github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql; to add it:
    go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
```

By issuing the suggested command `go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql`, you'll get the dependency added to your `go.mod` file and the contents of the package will be downloaded to your machine.

Your next execution will work:

```
$ go run main.go
Hello world
```

---

I've made some small modifications to your code to work, I'll add them here for completeness:

- I've used the same source, but changed the `package` name to `main`.
- I've added a main function to the bottom of the file:

```golang
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello world")

    _, err := Connect("username", "password", "localhost", "db")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

- I've saved to a file named `main.go`
- I've initialized the `go.mod` file by running `go mod init test` and `go mod tidy`, then I took the steps described on the beginning of the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry to make you feel confused with what I asked. Here I am just a student taking a course where I just install vscode and go. I got the github file from the course, but I'm still confused why I got an error when I wanted to run the go coding. I'm also not good at typing English too so maybe that's what makes you feel confused. I'm very sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you read the tutorial for an older go version.
Go 1.17 requires dependencies must be explicitly in `go.mod`.

Maybe you could try go module first (https://go.dev/blog/using-go-modules)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).